# Showing that gambler's ruin conditioned on being absorbed is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given a sample space $I=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ and $p>1/2$, the gambler's ruin is given by transition probabilities $p_{00} = 1$, $p_{i,i-1} = 1-p$ for $i\leq 1$, $p_{i,i+1} = p$ for $i\leq 1$.

If we know that the Markov chain is absorbed at 0 (let's call this event $A$), we can consider the conditional distribution $Y_n = X_n| A$. Intuitively $Y_n$ is also a Markov chain, but how do we show this rigorously?